# Why my python code for Binary Search Tree is showing this weird error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Here is my code. I can't understand what I'm missing.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data,left = None,right = None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class BST:
    def __init__(self,root=None):
        self.root = root
    def insert(self,val):
        new_node = Node(val)

        if self.root == None:
            self.root = new_node

        else:           
            cur = self.root
            leaf = None
            while cur!=None:
                leaf = cur
                if val >= cur.data:
                    cur = cur.right
                else:
                    cur = cur.left
            if val >= leaf.data:
                leaf.right = new_node
            else:
                leaf.left = new_node

    def preOrder(self,root):

        if root:
            print(root.data,end=' ')

            preOrder(root.left)
            preOrder(root.right)


b = BST()
b.insert(1)
b.insert(2)
b.insert(5)
b.insert(3)
b.insert(6)
b.insert(4)
b.preOrder(b.root)
```

This code is showing this error: **NameError: name 'preOrder' is not defined** How does it possible? I've defined the preOrder() in class BST. How can I solve this problem? And please explain the error so that I can understand my misunderstanding.

Comment: All attributes must be accessed via the class/instance namespace. Use `self.preOrder`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh! You have saved my day! Thank You.